# Removing duplicate emails in Sendgrid multiple email requests

Tags: sendgrid, twilio-api

Sendgrid has limitation that it can send emails for 1000 recipients and in this request it removes the duplicate emails. But as our recipient list is larger than that we need to send it over a multiple requests. Some times this requests get sent twice and receipient ends up with duplicate emails.
We use categories to link these multiple request. How to remove duplicate emails over multiple requests?

I tried grouping them based on batch_id but couldn't find anything to stop sending duplicate emails.

```
curl --location 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text/html",
            "value": "<html><head><title></title></head><body>Test</body></html>"
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "email": "abc@mail.com",
        "name": "Example"
    },
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "subject": "Testing",
            "to": [
                {
                    "email": "xyz@mail.com",
                    "name": "Exmple"
                }
```

If I send this curl twice, recipients will receive the mail twice. I want that if the same request is sent twice second request should be rejected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.